# python string variable length splitting with nested dict

Tags: python

I have a nested dict in the form of :

```
dict : {
    NAME1 :{
            FIELDS :{
                FIELD1 :{
                    MAXBIT:2, MINBIT:0},
                FIELD2 :{
                    MAXBIT:4, MINBIT:3},
                FIELD3 :{
                    MAXBIT:7, MINBIT:5}}}
    NAME2
    ....
    }
```

I want to write a function that takes a `NAME` and a `hex` value, and returns binary decomposition of `hex` according to `dict`.

Example:
for input `f(NAME1, 0x0f)` (`0x0f` is 00001111) and the above dict, output will be:

```
NAME1:
    FIELD1: 111
    FIELD2: 01
    FIELD3: 000
```

binary string is composed of fields, each field has it's length in bits.
pretty printing is not important, I'm just looking for the pythonic way to do it. Here's what I wrote:

```
def f(name1, hex_value):
    fields = []
    for field, value in dictionary[name1]['FIELDS'].items():
        fields.append([value['MINBIT'], value['MAXBIT'], field])
    fields.sort()
    binary_string = '{0:b}'.format(int(hex_value, 16))
    chunks = [bit_pair[1]-bit_pair[0]+1 for bit_pair in fields]
    rev_bin_sring = reversed(binary_string)
    sliced_fields = [''.join(islice(rev_bin_sring, i)) for i in chunks]
    sliced_fields = [string.replace('', '0') for string in sliced_fields]
    final_res = [list((field[2], bin_value)) for bin_value, field in zip(sliced_fields, fields)]
```

but it looks pretty ugly, I'm sure there's a more elegant way.

Comment: Why? How is the hex parameter related to the output?

Comment: @LutzHorn `0x0f` is `15` is `00001111`

Comment: I've edited to make it more clear

Comment: What exactly are `MAXBIT` and `MINBIT`?

Comment: binary string is composed of fields, each field has it's length in bits

Comment: Shouldn't field3 be 4 bits long then?

Comment: you're right, a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've renamed your `dict` as `d` since `dict` is a builtin python object type and you really shouldn't be overwriting those with your own variables:

```
d = {
   'NAME1' :{
       'FIELDS' :{
           'FIELD1' :{
               'MAXBIT':2, 'MINBIT':0},
           'FIELD2' :{
               'MAXBIT':4, 'MINBIT':3},
           'FIELD3' :{
               'MAXBIT':7, 'MINBIT':5}}}}

def f(name, hex_value):
    fields = d[name]['FIELDS'] 
    bin_value = bin(hex_value).replace('b','0')[::-1]
    new_d = {name:{}} 
    for field, value in fields.items():
        max_b, min_b = value['MAXBIT']+1, value['MINBIT']
        bin_value += '0'*(max_b-len(bin_value))
        new_d[name][field] = bin_value[min_b:max_b][::-1]
    return new_d
```

This first gets the relevant fields based on the `name` argument from the dictionary `d`.  Then it uses the `bin` function to convert the `hex_value` to a binary representation (as a string). The first two characters of `bin_value` will be `0b` so replace the `b` with another `0` and reverse the string (this will allow you to get your values using string slices later on). Now, for each `MAXBIT`, `MINBIT` pair you can slice your `bin_value` string and then reverse it (using `[::-1]`) to get your intended decomposition.  Obviously this will fail if your `bin_value` is shorter than the `max_b` value. To accommodate this, you can pad extra `'0'`s on the end of `bin_value` so that `bin_value` is at least `max_b` characters long.  Also note that `max_b = value['MAXBIT'] + 1` since you want to include the character at the index of `max_b` but python slices exclusively, so you add `1`.

```
>>> f('NAME1',0x0f)
{'NAME1': {'FIELD1': '111', 'FIELD2': '01', 'FIELD3': '000'}}
```

**EDIT**

A slightly different alternative that doesn't require all that reversing back and forth:

```
def f(name, hex_value):
    fields = d[name]['FIELDS'] 
    bin_value = bin(hex_value).replace('b','0')
    new_d = {name:{}}
    for field, value in fields.items():
        max_b, min_b = value['MAXBIT']+1 , value['MINBIT']
        new_d[name][field] = bin_value.zfill(max_b)[-max_b:-min_b or None]
    return new_d

>>> f('NAME1',0x0f)
{'NAME1': {'FIELD1': '111', 'FIELD2': '01', 'FIELD3': '000'}}
```

Note: the `value['MINBIT'] or None` handles the case where `value['MINBIT']` is zero.

Comment: I liked the version without reversal, easy to read and simple .

Comment: I still get "bad operand type for unary -: 'NoneType'", because it tries to slice the string with [-None]